# Fundamental group of a plane united with a circle in 3D space

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $X=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=9\}\cup\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3|(x-4)^2+y^2=1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$

Find the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,p_0)$ where $p_0=(3,0,0)$

Possible solution: I'm trying to use van Kampen principle. We have a plane that is tangent to a circle. I believe that I need to divide my space into two open sets.

Let $U = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2<10\}\cap X$ And $V$ is a sphere with some radius (lets say $3$) based in the center of the circle, intersected with $X$.

I believe the next steps are these (But I don't know how to prove all of them):

$1$. $U\cup V=X$ (this is trivial)

$2$. $U\cap V$ is path-connected with a trivial fundamental group

$3$. The fundamental group of $U$ is trivial (this is easy)

$4$. The fundamental group of $V$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ (this is known)

$5$. Thus $\pi_1(X,p_0) = \mathbb{Z}$. I believe this is possible because of point $2$ but I am not sure why.

Please help.

Comment: You may enjoy [this blog post](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences).

Comment: Can you prove that any loop on $X$ is homotopic to a loop only on $B$?